# Twitter's typeahead example / dynamic query

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, typeahead, typeahead.js

I am searching for an example for [twitter's typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).

I want to get the data with a function, should I use remote?
The returned from the server data would be a Json (not simply an array).
From those I want to display only the field e.g. `name`.

Upon selection of the correct `name` I want to run another function that e.g. alerts the `id` and the `description` (fields) of that object. Probably with [`typeahead:autocompleted`](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#custom-events) event binder ?

**Update/ sample:**

The `Dajaxice.async.get_closest_events()` bellow sends 3 parameters to the internal server (lat,lng, query). Query is the value the users has written. It returns an array (`venuesNames`) which is going to be displayed in the dropdown.

```
$( "#locationQueryInput" ).typeahead({
    remote:{
        replace: function (query ) {
            //alert($("locationQueryInput").val());
            Dajaxice.async.get_closest_events( 
                (function(data){                                            
                    venuesNames = []
                    venuesDetails = []
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.fVenues.length; i++) {
                        venuesNames.push(data.fVenues[i].name)
                        venuesDetails[ data.fVenues[i].name ] = {
                                                'id' : data.fVenues[i].id,
                                                'lat' : data.fVenues[i].lat,
                                                'lng' : data.fVenues[i].lng,
                                                'address' :data.fVenues[i].address,
                                                'city' :data.fVenues[i].city,
                        }
                    }
                    return venuesNames
                }), 
                {'lat' : new_marker_latlng.lat, 'lng' : new_marker_latlng.lng, 'query' : query }  
            );
        }


    }

}).bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj,datum){
// do stuff upon completion
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good example of using a json response: [How to render JSON response using latest typeahead.js library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287102/how-to-render-json-response-using-latest-typeahead-js-library).

And then to bind the event, you'd combine the above suggestion with something like:

```
$('.selector').typeahead({
    // base this part on example link given above...
}).bind('typeahead:autocompleted', function (obj, datum) {
    console.log(datum);  // datum will contain the value that was autocompleted
});
```

**Update 1:**
Regarding the query parameter, your function call is written incorrectly.  According to the docs:

> replace – A function with the signature replace(url, uriEncodedQuery)
>   that can be used to override the request URL. Expected to return a
>   valid URL. If set, no wildcard substitution will be performed on url.

So you need to pass the URL as the first parameter, and the query string as the second:

```
remote:{
    replace: function (url, query ) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Question, how can I get the query input value? `$('input').val()` is not working because of the html layout.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to get the value in the 'typeahead:autocomplete' event handler.  Note that you may also want to capture the 'typeahead:selected' event for when someone explicitly clicks an item in the dropdown list.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I meant how to get the query in the server  request. I updated my question with a sample code I have so far.